# KUBUNTU 16.04 How do I set custom keybinds?

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys

Whenever I go to press the "INPUT" button, and press down the keys for my Keybinds, they don't *stick*. When I release the key-combination, it just resets.

I am simply trying to set the keybind of opening the KDE Dash to Meta, but as I said, it won't record and save the buttons I press when I want to create the keybind.

Comment: What is this "INPUT" button? It's possible that `Meta` is a reserved key when pressed alone to bring up the menu.

Comment: The INPUT button is the button I press to activate the state where the keyboard reads and saves the buttons I press to the keybind. So If I press the INPUT button, press CTRL-T, then I set the keybind to CTRL-T. 
The original keybind for opening the menu was Meta. I then moved the menu to another panel, and it removed the hotkey. Whenever I try to set Meta as the keybind, it does not allow me to do it. Only Meta + something else.